# EasyOCR Module Not Found Error Despite Successful Install

Tags: python, ocr

I'm trying to run a python file that utilizes easyocr but despite a successful install, I can't get it to recognize that I have easyocr installed. Does anyone know why that is?

Please see below for the install and response in Anaconda:

```
(base) C:\Users\[username]\Desktop >pip install easyocr
Collecting easyocr
  Using cached easyocr-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (63.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow<8.3.0 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python-headless in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (4.5.1.48)
Requirement already satisfied: python-bidi in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision>=0.5 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch->easyocr) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-bidi->easyocr) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->easyocr) (3.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.0 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->easyocr) (2.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: imageio>=2.3.0 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->easyocr) (2.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tifffile>=2019.7.26 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->easyocr) (2021.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets>=1.1.1 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->easyocr) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0->scikit-image->easyocr) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0->scikit-image->easyocr) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0->scikit-image->easyocr) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0->scikit-image->easyocr) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<5,>=4.3 in c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.0->scikit-image->easyocr) (4.4.2)
Installing collected packages: easyocr
Successfully installed easyocr-1.4.1

(base) C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ocr import OCR
  File "C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\ ocr.py", line 3, in <module>
    import easyocr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easyocr'
```